Facebook API , Add CTA Button to Multiple-photos Post using Page-id/feed
After uploading the photos I tried to create a  ‘multiple-photos’ post with a Call To Action button attached to it, the issue is that the post is being created successfully when I don’t include the CTA but when I add the CTA button (2nd code block) the post is created without the photos, here below are the payloads I used on [POST] /{page_id}/feed.
//This will create the Post with Album as a type successfully
{
  "access_token": "<access_token>",
  "published": 1,
  "message": "An awesome Fb Post",
  "attached_media": [
    { "media_fbid": "<uploaded_photo_id>" },
    { "media_fbid": "<uploaded_photo_id>" }
  ]
}

//The Post will be created with the Call To Action Button but without photos
{
  "access_token": "<access_token>",
  "published": 1,
  "message": "An awesome Fb Post",
  "attached_media": [
    { "media_fbid": "<uploaded_photo_id>" },
    { "media_fbid": "<uploaded_photo_id>" }
  ],
  "call_to_action": {
    "type": "MESSAGE_PAGE",
    "value": {
      "app_destination": "MESSENGER",
      "link": "https://fb.com/messenger_doc/"
    }
  }
}

Any Idea why the Post is not being created with both the images and the CTA button?
Thanks & I appreciate any feedback
I wish to use the created post in an AdCreative later on.
